# Filtering network traffic with an application

Tags: networking, firewall, arp

I'm trying to create a system to filter out certain types of internet traffic on a network. Basically, I'd like to be able to inspect packets that are destined for the internet and choose whether to let them through or to simply drop them (think UDP packets).

The rules for deciding are rather complex and can't be written as simple firewall rules. I'd like to write a program to make this determination.

I've built a Linux system and am using arpspoof to ensure that all of the network traffic flows through this system. I know that I can set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward to 0 or 1 to block all traffic from being forwarded or allowing everything through. I can also write firewall rules to do simple things.

How do I get all of the traffic to go through a program I've written to decide whether the data should be forwarded or dropped? What sorts of tools or systems should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

```
# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Then write your own userspace program.
https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/using-nfqueue-and-libnetfilter_queue/

But I think netfilter has already all capabilities what you want; you can write very complex rules with `iptables`/`nftables`.